# Simplifying large coefficients in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I use SymPy for symbolic calculations in Python and get e.g. an expression like

```
Z =  2.02416176758139e+229 / (2.42579446609411e+232 * s + 9.8784848517664e+231)
```

Is there a function in SymPy (e.g. in sympy.simplify?) to get something like

```
Z = 2.024 / (2425.8 * s + 987.8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intent of your request can be met by allowing cancellation:

```
>>> 1/(1/Z)
1/(1198.41926912424*second + 488.028427864731)
```

or

```
>>> factor(Z)
0.00083443251102827/(1.0*second + 0.407226786516346)
```

But there is no built-in method of accessing the exponent in an exponential form.

Comment: This should now happen automatically in the current master branch of SymPy.